# How to get React.Children of the component

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React. Now I am trying to get to know, how to use `React.Children` right way, but despite numerous attempts and reading docs I permanently fail. I am afraid I overlook something trivial. 
Here is dummy example.

May you explain me, why `React.Children.count` is 0? I would expect 5. What do I do wrong?

```
class Author extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.Name} {this.props.Surname}
      </div>
      )
  }
}


class Express extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.doClick = this.doClick.bind(this);
  }

  doClick() {
     alert(React.Children.count(this.props.children)); // outcome is 0 (?)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.doClick}>
        <div>Science</div>
        <Author Name="Mario" Surname="Puzzo"/>
        <Author Name="Maria" Surname="Devita"/>
        <div>Literature</div>
        <div>History</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Express />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: `children` would be components nested within the call to your `Author` component not components in your render function e.g. `<Author>{/* children go here */}</Author>`. Example from the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I try you to understand, but I do not get it. There are beautiful 5 (or 2 ? )children nested in div tag, I do not have a clue, what could be more childish.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: thanks for the link above, it threw shed of light on what I needed to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React docs:**

```
React.Children.count(children):
    Returns the total number of components in children, equal to the number of times that a callback passed to map or forEach would be invoked.
```

In your example, i can conclude that your **Express** component doesn't have any children, so it's normal to have 0 as an outcome of `React.Children.count(this.props.children)`. Also, you should have the same outcome if you try to get the count of children in your **Author** component.

try to redefine it like so:

```
import React from 'react';

const Author = ({ children, id }) => {
    alert(`child ${id}: ${React.Children.count(children)} children`); // outcome is 2 for the first child Author and 1 for the second
    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
};

const Express = () => (
      <div>
          <div>Science</div>
          <Author id="1">
              <div>Mario Puzzo</div>
              <div>Mario2 Puzzo2</div>
          </Author>
          <Author id="2">
              <div>Maria Devita</div>
          </Author>
          <div>Literature</div>
          <div>History</div>
      </div>
);

export default Express;
```

And to have more explanation, try to visit this link [React.children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)

Comment: Thank you very much. I compare your answer with https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html and now I see the sence. I was not familiar with this concept. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @lyborko You're welcome. React may seems confusing at first but it's an amazing library once you understand its concepts. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a functional component and render the children you can do this:

```
export const EZForm = (props) => {   
     return (     
       <form>     
         {props.children}
       </form>        
    );
}
```

Then wherever you call the component

```
import { EZForm } from './EZForm';
<EZForm>
  <p>Wonderful</p>
</EZForm>
```

Remember, props.children or React.Children are not iterable.  If you care to get the total number of children or iterate them you can do these.  You can also use spread operator:

```
import React from 'react';

export const EZForm = (props) => {   
 return (   
  <div>   
    {props.children} 
     <div>{React.Children.toArray(props.children).length}</div>
     <div>{Array.from(props.children).length}</div> 
     <div>{[...props.children].length}</div>
   </div>           
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the Author component doesn't have any children. And from the code provided we can't tell if the Express component was passed any children.

In your Express component if you use: this is a child

and then in your Author component `alert(React.Children.count(this.props.children)`
 you should get a result that isn't 0.